# ¿Cómo detectar el scroll con javascript y cuantificarlo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un Banner, que tiene un "background-attachment: fixed", y quisiera que tuviera una animación que a medida de que hiciera scroll tuviese una opacidad menor; vi que esto se puede hacer con jquery, mas no con javascript puro. Seria de gran utilidad saber si no hay alguna librería que detecte el scroll o como hacerlo con javascript puro.

Este es mi código:

Html:

`<header>
        <div class="bienvenida">
            <h1>¡Bienvenid@!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="banner"></div>
    </header>`

CSS:

```
.banner{
background: url(../images/banner5.jpg);
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 49vh;
object-fit: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estoy utilizando el evento scroll para el `window`.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(evt) {...
```

Estoy calculando la transparencia relativo al desplazamiento de la ventana en y `window.scrollY` y de la altura de la ventana `window.innerHeight`.

```
let transparencia = window.scrollY / window.innerHeight * 2
```

Después establezco la opacidad del banner como `1 - transparencia`.

Espero que sea útil.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(evt) {
  let transparencia = window.scrollY / window.innerHeight * 2
  transparencia = transparencia < 1 ? transparencia : 1;
  banner.style.opacity = 1 - transparencia  
}, false);
```

```css
.banner{
background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553264646-7eb44743436f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ);
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 49vh;
object-fit: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}

main{height:1000px;background:#d9d9d9}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="bienvenida">
            <h1>¡Bienvenid@!</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="banner" class="banner"></div>
    </header>
<main></main>
```

#### Actualización

El OP comenta:

> ¿y si fuera un blur como podría aplicar este código?

En este caso necesitas calcular el valor para el blur. A diferencia de `opacity` que toma valores entre 0 y 1 para el blur necesitas valores entre 0 y lo que fuera.
Estoy calculando el blur como

```
let blur = window.scrollY / 10;
```

Después cambio los estilos del banner aplicando un filtro css:

```
 banner.style.filter  = `blur(${blur}px)`;
```

A continuación viene una demo:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(evt) {
  let blur = window.scrollY / 10;
  
  banner.style.filter  = `blur(${blur}px)`; 

}, false);
```

```css
.banner{
background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553264646-7eb44743436f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ);
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 49vh;
object-fit: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


main{height:1000px;background:#d9d9d9}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="bienvenida">
            <h1>¡Bienvenid@!</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="banner" class="banner"></div>
    </header>
<main></main>
```

Comment: ¿y si fuera un blur como podría aplicar este codigo?